# multithreaded websocket++ server crashes

Tags: c++, multithreading, websocket++

I modified the [websocket++ echo server example](https://github.com/zaphoyd/websocketpp/blob/master/examples/echo_server/echo_server.cpp) to use multiple threads:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <boost/thread/thread.hpp>
#include <websocketpp/config/asio_no_tls.hpp>
#include <websocketpp/server.hpp>

typedef websocketpp::server<websocketpp::config::asio> server;

using websocketpp::lib::placeholders::_1;
using websocketpp::lib::placeholders::_2;
using websocketpp::lib::bind;

// pull out the type of messages sent by our config
typedef server::message_ptr message_ptr;

// Define a callback to handle incoming messages
void on_message(server* s, websocketpp::connection_hdl hdl, message_ptr msg)
{
    try {
        s->send(hdl, msg->get_payload(), msg->get_opcode());
    } catch (const websocketpp::lib::error_code& e) {
        std::cout << "Echo failed because: " << e << "(" << e.message() << ")" << std::endl;
    }
}

int main()
{
    // Create a server endpoint
    server echo_server;
    boost::asio::io_service io_service;
    try {

        // Initialize Asio
        echo_server.init_asio(&io_service);

        // Register our message handler
        echo_server.set_message_handler(bind(&on_message, &echo_server, ::_1, ::_2));

        // Listen on port 9002
        echo_server.set_reuse_addr(true);
        echo_server.listen(9002);

        // Start the server accept loop
        echo_server.start_accept();

        boost::thread_group threadpool;
        threadpool.create_thread(boost::bind(&boost::asio::io_service::run, &io_service));
        threadpool.create_thread(boost::bind(&boost::asio::io_service::run, &io_service));
        threadpool.join_all();
    } catch (websocketpp::exception const& e) {
        std::cout << e.what() << std::endl;
    } catch (...) {
        std::cout << "other exception" << std::endl;
    }
}
```

I connect using one client which sends many messages asynchronously. Then the server crashes with:

```
2016-08-31 13:05:44] [info] asio async_read_at_least error: system:125 (Operation canceled)
[2016-08-31 13:05:44] [error] handle_read_frame error: websocketpp.transport:2 (Underlying Transport Error)
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'std::bad_weak_ptr'
  what():  bad_weak_ptr
```

Judging from the [websocket++ manual on Thread Safety](https://www.zaphoyd.com/websocketpp/manual/reference/thread-safety), what I am doing should be threadsafe:

> The Asio transport provides full thread safety for endpoint. Works
>   with an io_service thread pool where multiple threads are calling
>   io_service.run();
>
> ...
>
> All core transports guarantee that the handlers for a given connection
>   will be serialized. When the transport and concurrency policies
>   support endpoint concurrency, anything involving a connection_hdl
>   should be thread safe. i.e. It is safe to pass connection_hdls to
>   other threads, store them indefinitely, and call endpoint methods that
>   take them as parameters from any thread at any time.

**What am I missing here?**

---

The client I am using is based on NodeJS:

**client.js**

```
var port =  9002;
var times = 10000;
var WebSocket = require("ws");
var ws = new WebSocket("ws://localhost:" + port);

ws.on('open', function open() {
    for(var i = 0; i < times; ++i) {
        ws.send(i);
    }
});
```

start via:

```
$ npm install --save ws
$ node client.js
```

Comment: Is `s->send` safe for concurrent invocations?

Comment: @DavidSchwartz I assume so, yes.

Comment: How do you test it? Can you post the client code as well (maybe via a link)?

Comment: @RustyX I updated my question with the client code

Comment: It is working fine on MSVC 15 and boost 61.

Comment: @RustyX thanks for trying it out, I suspect this might be a bug then, I'll report it